# gevent uwsgi plugin not loading in Alpine docker

Tags: python, docker, uwsgi, gevent, alpine-linux

I'm trying to boot a simple uWSGI server on Alpine docker image (3.9). Here is the Python script

```py
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

And I'm trying to start it using the following command:

```sh
uwsgi --plugins http,python3,gevent --http :8081 --uid nobody --gid nobody --wsgi-file hello.py --module hello --master --processes 4 --gevent 2 --gevent-monkey-patch --socket /tmp/uswgi.sock
```

However, every time I try this I get this error:

```sh
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: Error relocating /usr/lib/uwsgi/gevent_plugin.so: PyInt_FromLong: symbol not found !!!
uwsgi: unrecognized option: gevent
getopt_long() error
```

I've tried installing `python3-dev` package, but the command still fails. Does anyone has idea why this happens? Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.9.3

RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
  python3 \
  python3-dev \
  uwsgi \
  uwsgi-python3 \
  uwsgi-http \
  uwsgi-gevent

CMD ["sh"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uwsgi-gevent` is the Python 2 uWSGI plugin:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/main/x86_64/uwsgi-gevent

For Python 3, you'd need [`uwsgi-gevent3`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/main/x86_64/uwsgi-gevent3).

Also, you're missing the [`py3-gevent`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/community/x86_64/py3-gevent) package for the gevent Python module.

In summary, updated package list:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
  python3 \
  python3-dev \
  py3-gevent \
  uwsgi \
  uwsgi-python3 \
  uwsgi-http \
  uwsgi-gevent3
```

Plus, don't forget to use the `gevent3` plugin instead of `gevent`:

```
uwsgi --plugins http,python3,gevent3
```